# What is the usage of tag over the cell in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I found that, in jupyter notebook, there is a tag tool over the cell, which can be activated by "View - Cell Toolbar - Tags". But I can not figure out, why we need these tags. Can someone give some suggestions or usage examples?

[image]

Comment: For people looking for tags in JupyterLab: it was added in [v2.0](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/changelog.html#v2-0-0) (at the Release Candidate stage as of March 2020). Prior to that (JupyterLab ≤ 1.x), the [jupyterlab-celltags](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-celltags/) was needed.

Comment: One usage of tags is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084050/2822346: how to hide specific cells using tags and `nbconvert`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tagging is a fairly recent and perhaps not quite finished feature of jupyter-notebooks, added with [version 5.0](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#cell-tags). From what I understand they are mostly meant for tools such as [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (converts notebooks to other formats such as pdf) and [nbval](https://github.com/computationalmodelling/nbval) (validates notebooks) and other more or less integrated tools working with jupyter notebooks. Being able to add tags to a cell would enable different behaviours for such tools depending on a cells tag. Some example that could be accomplished with the ability to add tags would be:

- nbconvert - hide a cell, hide the input leaving the output visible,
  collapse a cell leaving a way to reveal it
- nbconvert to latex - markdown cell contains title (or subtitle, abstract...)
- nbval - check/ignore output from a cell, skip executing a cell, expect a cell
  to raise an error
- nbgrader - solution cell, tests cell
- nbparameterise - cell contains input parameters.

as envisaged by takluyver over at [jupyter's github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2048#issuecomment-283695460). If you want more information on implementation and the discussion surrounding it you can read more [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2048/).

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Christian's answer, there is an important utility you can get from using tags. You can run all cells and keep running even when encountering runtime errors. You flag a cell with `raises-exception` tag. Very useful for educational purposes. [Source](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4993).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Christian above, one great use is to provide different input parameters value to this notebook program, nbparameterise is one example. [See here](https://github.com/takluyver/nbparameterise). Papermill is another one: [see here](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)

From a user perspective, one can probably achieve the same thing by using env variable os.getenv(), or getting from command line argument sys.getargv(), but adding tag to a cell seems to be the easiest.

Under the hood, the jupyter notebook is saved as a json file. Let says you tag the first cell as Parameters, and declare variables var1=10 and var2 ='adam'. The json file would look something like below, and the tags is in the metadata section. So it is simple for a tool to parse this json and get to the tags section, and say replace the variables with different values.

```
{
  "cells": [
  {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "tags": [
        "Parameters"
      ]
    }, 
    ....
  },
  "source": [
    "var1 = 10",
    "var2 = 'adam'"
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another usage is for papermill.

Papermill is a useful tool you can use to run notebooks from the CLI (as part of a script or from CRON or such).

Papermill uses tags to be able to parametrize a notebook so you can have some global parameters in your notebook and then run that notebook multiple times with different parameter values automatically

source: https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-parameterize.html