# Hide some cells when converting ipython notebook to notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am trying to hide some specific cells when converting an IPython notebook to a notebook. I'd like to use notebooks in class and want to generate 'exercise' notebooks from a master notebook that contains both questions and answers.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517194/how-to-hide-one-specific-cell-input-or-output-in-ipython-notebook) was very helpful, but for some reason the approach using tags and the preprocessor does not work when converting a notebook to a notebook (it does work when converting to PDF and HTML).

Any thoughts, hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple to do with [nbformat](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (installed with jupyter already):

```
import nbformat
nb = nbformat.read('Untitled6.ipynb', as_version=4)
for cell in nb.cells.copy():
    if 'remove_cell' in cell.metadata.get('tags', []):
        nb.cells.remove(cell)
nbformat.write(nb, 'Untitled7.ipynb')
```