# Remove cells from Jupyter Notebook with nbconvert

Tags: jupyter, nbconvert

Recommendations mentioned in [How to hide one specific cell (input or output) in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517194/how-to-hide-one-specific-cell-input-or-output-in-ipython-notebook) don't work.

On Windows I do the following

```
jupyter nbconvert a.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags="{'remove_cell'}"
```

but get an error

```
traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'remove_cell_tags' trait of a TagRemovePreprocessor instance must be a set, but a value of type 'unicode' (i.e. u"{'remove_cell'}") was specified.
```

I also tried '{"remove_cell"}'

I am using nbconvert 5.4.0

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the TagRemovePreprocessor before you call it.

The code below shows how to enable it and how to enclose your tags as a list so you can exclude more than one tag if you wish. To exclude a single tag, just put one element in the list eg ['remove_cell'].

The parameter --to html is not required if you are converting to html (as html is the default). If you want to convert to python, for example, change --to html to --to python

`jupyter nbconvert a.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags="['remove_cell', 'other_tag_to_remove']" --to html`

Note that the TagRemovePreprocessor is only available in nbconvert 5.3 and above: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=TagRemovePreprocessor

Comment: I needed to surround the `remove_cell_tags` value with single quotes instead of double-quotes to get it to work on Windows 10 in Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

Needs some extra quoting to work:

`--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags={\"remove_cell\"}`.

However beware of an ongoing issue with noteboot to notebook conversion - it seems like in this case preprocessors, including tag removal, do not run. See more in this SO question:

[jupyter nbconvert --to notebook not excluding raw cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974582/jupyter-nbconvert-to-notebook-not-excluding-raw-cells/54290950#54290950)

Update: Not tested on windows, just on Linux