# jupyter nbconvert --to notebook not excluding raw cells

Tags: makefile, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm trying to export notebooks from a `./doc` folder to a `./notebook/ folder in the root of my project, but remove all the raw cells where I have rst.

I tried the following:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook $< --output=$@ --TemplateExporter.exclude_raw=True
```

I'm doing this in a Makefile (so the `$<` and `$@` are the name of the local notebooks and the name of the notebook once it is moved to the top-level `./notebook` dir, respectively).

It runs, but the raw cells are still there in the copies of the notebooks. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be due to a bug - when the output format is 'notebook', then nbconverts seems to take a short cut, bypassing preprocessors.

I've come across at least one more issue on github related to it:
https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/895

Here is my workaround.

1. Create a custom template file `custom_notebook.tpl` with the following content:

```
{% extends 'null.tpl'%}

{%- block body %}
{{ nb | json_dumps }}
{% endblock body %}
```

This essentially copies the notebook, but allows preprocessors to run.

2. In the command line replace `--to notebook` with `--to custom --template=custom_notebook.tpl`

The result will be a valid notebook with filters run on it. I have not tested with `--TemplateExporter.exclude_raw=True` but it worked with `--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags` that suffered the same null effect with `--to notebook` option.