# How to skip specific cells while converting a notebook to python script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub, nbconvert

I am trying to convert a Jupyter notebook to a python file using [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) command. There is a cell having Python code which I want it to skip while converting. I tried few solutions including adding remove_cell tag to the one that has to be skipped:

```
"jupyter nbconvert <notebook_path> --TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags=\"['remove_cell']\" --to script
```

But it did not work. Please let me know if this can be done through nbconvert.

Comment: Sounds like it would just be easier to open the .py file after and remove manually

Comment: Note that the TagRemovePreprocessor is only available in nbconvert 5.3 and above: `https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=TagRemovePreprocessor`

Comment: @KurtisStreutker The requirement is to get rid of manual editing of python file. Please suggest a way if you know about it. Thank you in advance

Comment: @SreeramNair I'm on version 5.4.0 but I believe TagRemovePreprocessor  converts a notebook from one form to another, but not to python script or .py format. Please correct me if I'm wrong, with a working example if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question needs a somewhat better specification (what is the output you get, in the script and on screen; code fragments; etc).

Even so, a few things you may try:

1. Using `--to python` instead of -`-to script` (see [this](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/764), although it may be old for your version).
2. Change delimiters for the tag.
   In an example in the link above: `--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='{"note"}'`.
   In [this other example](http://--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags=%7B%5C%22Hide%5C%22%7D): `--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags={\"Hide\"}`
   And [some more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834910/remove-cells-from-jupyter-notebook-with-nbconvert).

Comment: @Arjun - Which of the two?