# Is there a way to hide a cell in sageMath (8.8) after evaluating it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sage

I'm running sageMath 8.8 in Jupyter Notebooks (which uses Python 2.7 as its kernel) in Windows 10.

I would like to hide cells with code after evaluating. Ideally I'd like a way to toggle so the page isn't cluttered with code but the code is still accessible when someone wants to see it.

Comment: Hmm, that is more of a Jupyter question.  Depending on where you are running them, this might be possible, especially in the CoCalc custom Jupyter version.  I assume using `%hide` at the top of a cell doesn't work like it did in the legacy Sage notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but [adding metadata to cells](https://jupyter.org/jupyter-book/features/hiding.html) for hiding probably could be done programmatically.  [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/Zsailer/5d1f4e357c78409dd9a5a4e5c61be552) also seems plausible, and [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517194/how-to-hide-one-specific-cell-input-or-output-in-ipython-notebook?rq=1) details how to use an extension for it, though I haven't used it myself.