# Can you hide code cell outputs in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to hide a single code cell's output in Google Colab?

No one needs to see the sea of `pip` logs when we install things:

[image]

If you look at the screenshot you'll see I tried to apply one of the solutions from this similar Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084050/1762493

I tried applying `TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_single_output_tags` as a `#comment`, a `@@Magic`, and a `!command` but those don't work with this line.

I checked Colab's "Welcome" and "Resource" notebooks but didn't notice anything there for deeper notebook settings: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found this answer and applied it successfully: https://serverfault.com/a/41968/328943

Simply adding `&> /dev/null` to the tail of any command will silence its output outside of any errors that may arise.

Like so:

`!pip install gwpy &> /dev/null`

Comment: this does not work for % commands

Answer (score 70):

In this case you can just use

```
!pip install -q gwpy
```

In general, you can start the cell with %%capture

```
%%capture
# the rest of your code
```

Comment: This `%%capture` is what answers the title of the question - the tittle is general, although the example in the content of the question is specific to `pip`.

Comment: do you mind reasoning what "%% capture" does?

Answer (score 15):

This can be done by adding `--quiet` at the end. Thus for your case

```
!pip install gwpy --quiet
```

Answer (score 13):

Just select the cell and press `Ctrl+ M O`. This will hide the output of the cell. This option is also available under the view tab.

Comment: Thanks! This feels like the only answer to the actual question. What a confusing UI...

Comment: Thank you, but still my answer didn't qualify as an accepted answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Manage colab notebook by splitting it into sections, which can hide group of cells together with output. For instance, at the beginning I have "INIT" section, which loads pip's and necessary data from disk. One click, and initialized notebook is ready for work.
- Stable code I hide with snippet at the beginning of each cell.

#@title 'What does it do'

If needed, output can be cleared too.

Other useful snippets can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb)