# How to toggle the visibility of the markdown cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I must be missing something but I cannot find how one can toggle the visibility of the specific markdown cell in the jupyter document.

I know I can toggle the visibility of

- *all* *code* cells at once by enabling "Hide input all" nbextension
- a single *code* cell by enabling "Hide cell" nbextension
- a *code* cell(cells) by using solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664156)
- a markdown cell by clicking on left of it *provided* the cell contains the section marker, i.e. it begins with "#...".

But what about a markdown cell with plain text?
I'd like to stress that I'm not saying about "removing" the visibility of the tagged cells by filtering them out with nbconverter (like [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/removing_cells.html)).
I mean *interactive* toggling of the single plain markdown cell.

Comment: Are you seeking an answer specific for Jupyter Notebook interface, or JupyterLab would work as well?

Comment: @krassowski I'm interested in solving the problem in Jupyter Notebook.