Multiple versions of single Jupyter Notebook for different audiences (e.g. tutors/students) using tags
I'm working on creating assignments for students using Jupyter Notebooks. My goal is to generate different versions of the same Notebook to distribute to tutors and students.
I need certain cells, such as those containing exercise solutions, to be included only in the tutor's version, while other cells should be exclusive to the student's version. Sometimes, I want to remove entire cells, and other times, just the output.
I believe this can be achieved by tagging cells and using nbconvert to save the Notebook (.ipynb) into another .ipynb file.
A similar method was suggested for converting .ipynb to HTML here. I'm interested in hearing if anyone has experience, or creative new ideas, in creating different versions of a single Jupyter Notebook for various audiences.
My project is quite extensive, so I need an automated solution. While I could manually create different versions by copying and pasting if I only had a few Notebooks, this approach isn’t feasible for a larger scale.
Following initial comments, I tried assigning the tag "remove_cell" to some of the Notebook cells (example notebook here) and then removing them using the suggestion of this answer
jupyter nbconvert nbconvert-example.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='{"remove_cell"}'

However, the tagged cells are not removed when saving to Jupyter Notebook with the --to notebook option. They are only removed with the --to html option.

Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517194/how-to-hide-one-specific-cell-input-or-output-in-ipython-notebook ? So you'd create a master version of the notebook for tutors and tag the cells or output you want to remove from the student version. Use nbconvert to create a new notebook from input/tutor notebook. See https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#notebook-and-preprocessors for more details

ipynb files are just JSON blobs. It's not too hard to write your own processor if nbconvert doesn't do exactly what you want.

@Dunes Thanks for the link. The accepted answer seems to only work for HTML output. I tested it, but it doesn’t work for notebook output. While I could write a script to handle the JSON directly, I’m hoping there’s already a solution out there. It seems others must have faced similar needs.

What did you try? Did you look at the other link I gave. Only had to add --to notebook to get it working.

I like Dunes suggestion at the JSON level, sort of. Instead of writing your own processor, Jupyter has nbformat that has the concepts of cells and metadata and tags baked in. It is higher-level but much more customizable than nbconvert. See the top of here for a brief overview of nbformat and example of using it to make other notebooks. If you had to serve different versions, one way would be to have a central repo, and either use different branches or different repos and use actions or scripts when the central repo gets pushed to, ...

 that run and update the appropriate places. In the MyBinder world, there is postBuild that does this. Here I use that to get a tutorial from a developers' repo and use nbformat to update the notebook to include additional content I want in my fork. (More on MyBinder's postBuild concept here.) Or you can use GitHub Actions. ...

  I have all that sort of combined in one repo with branches here using Github Actions to make branches based on the main source. Then the launch buttons on the main page there will work. The one current minor hiccup is I have to remember to pull the changes to the branches that the actions due to my local.

Thanks, @Wayne for the comments and numerous links. However, a self-contained answer with detailed steps would be more useful for future reference.

@Dunes I tried the accepted answer jupyter nbconvert nbconvert-example.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='{"remove_cell"}', with the addition of --to notebook. As other commented, it works with --to html but does not remove the cells with tag remove_cell when using --to notebook. If you have a working solution, a detailed answer would be useful.

This is all built in to nbconvert. You can just do:
# ensure all output has been produced
jupyter nbconvert tutor-source-only.ipynb
    --to notebook \
    --execute
    --output tutor-with-output.ipynb

# remove cells that you want the students to figure out on their own and
# optionally remove the output of some/all cells, so the students have to 
# run the notebook 
jupyter nbconvert tutor-with-output.ipynb \
    --to notebook \
    --output student.ipynb \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled True \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags remove_cell \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_all_outputs_tags remove_output

I would advise against using TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags as the source is kept in the file, but the GUI is told not to show it.
For any cells where you want to show the students what the output should look like, but not how to produce it, I would recommend writing your own preprocessor that takes the cell, strips the input, and converts the cell to a markdown cell, copying across the output. That way the "output" remains when the students run the notebook.
You can find more on how to add and run your own preprocessors here: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html#Custom-Preprocessors

If you are used to programming in Python, using nbformat can add in all sorts of functionality based on tags and/or cell content. I has the concepts of the notebook, cell types, and much more, all baked in. Therefore it is great for iterating on notebooks and the content and making manipulations to result in new versions of the notebooks.
Here I use it to fix metadata for cells in a notebook meant to be run as slideshow. Adapting that and this example to edit markdown cells to see the remove_cell tag and remove it, would be something like this:
# Remove cells with "remove_cell"
import os
notebook_name = "tutor-source-only.ipynb"
student_notebook_name_prefix = "student" 

import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read(notebook_example, nbf.NO_CONVERT)
cells_to_keep = []
for cell in ntbk.cells:
    if cell.cell_type == "code":
        if "tags" in cell.metadata:
            if "remove_cell" not in cell.metadata.tags:
                cells_to_keep.append(cell)
    else:
        cells_to_keep.append(cell)
new_ntbk = ntbk
new_ntbk.cells = cells_to_keep
nbf.write(new_ntbk, student_notebook_name_prefix + notebook_name.split("only")[1], version=nbf.NO_CONVERT)

Then since you are using nbformat you can also include in your script removing any output you have tagged there for removal.
# Remove cells with "remove_cell" and drop output in kept cells if tagged with "remove_output" tag
import os
notebook_name = "tutor-source-only.ipynb"
student_notebook_name_prefix = "student" 

import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read(notebook_example, nbf.NO_CONVERT)
cells_to_keep = []
for cell in ntbk.cells:
    if cell.cell_type == "code":
        if "tags" in cell.metadata:
            if "remove_cell" not in cell.metadata.tags:
                if "remove_output" in cell.metadata.tags:
                    cell.outputs = []
                cells_to_keep.append(cell)
    else:
        cells_to_keep.append(cell)
new_ntbk = ntbk
new_ntbk.cells = cells_to_keep
nbf.write(new_ntbk, student_notebook_name_prefix + notebook_name.split("only")[1], version=nbf.NO_CONVERT)

(If you want to remove all output from the student versions, see my answer to  'Open Jupyter notebook without render images and without popolating [sic] dataframes - safe mode loading preventing out of memory state' here.)
If you wanted to execute the notebook, you can use nbconvert on the command line (as shown in Dunes' accepted answer) or via a script like in 'Using nbconvert as a library'.  I like Jupytext as a tool for this in my toolbox. Jupytext is convenient and I can use nbformat to do most of the heavy lifting separate from execution.
You'll note here in 'Using nbconvert as a library' that nbformat is often used in conjunction with nbformat.
If you want more examples with nbformat, I have many with code that you can see here and here.
