# can you put both text and computation in a jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to put randomly genreted results in a table in my jupyter-notebook but I know how to make a tab in the markdown mode (ie `esc` + `m` mode)
But I don't know how to put variables in it and i found no documentations on how to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use variables on an ipython notebook markup cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878083/can-i-use-variables-on-an-ipython-notebook-markup-cell)

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: My question was how to make a tab of random size using vectors so basically i have to be able either to iterate inside a markdown cell (but obviously i don't think i will be able to do that) or to pass in argument vectors in an elaborate markdown structure

Comment: But indeed i didn't found those question while i was searching and they are really close to what I want