# Print Variable In Jupyter Notebook Markdown Cell Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Can I print the value of a variable in Markdown Cell Jupyter Notebook?

Tried Code:

```
value = 5.3

Markdown cell --> Value is {{ value }}
```

I want that the Markdown cell should display the value of variable

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Screenshot for Code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use variables on an ipython notebook markup cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878083/can-i-use-variables-on-an-ipython-notebook-markup-cell)

Comment: If only Jupyter/Python had gone the [noweb](https://github.com/nrnrnr/noweb) route like RStudio/R, the world would be a better place. Sigh.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So After going through all the links I was able to resolve the problem by referring to nbextension jupyter notebook docs : https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

Steps Taken:

1. pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
2. jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
3. jupyter nbextension enable python-markdown/main

After the above commands started a jupyter notebook and to print the value of a variable in the markdown cells works like charm!

You just have to use **{{ ac_score }}**  within a markdown cell.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea about, how can we achieve the same in JupyterLab ?

Comment: I also had to make my notebook **trusted** and **enable the extension** via the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682662/8419574).

Answer (score 58):

[@nilansh bansal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874352/5251061) answer works great for Jupyter Notebooks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for JupyterLab because the plugin is no longer supported (as is the case for all nbextension plugins). Since JupyterLab gains popularity, I wanted to complement the answers so far because it took me quite some time to find a solution. This is because until now there is no plugin compatible with JupyterLab. I have found the following solution for myself by combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310524/5251061) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443437/removing-certain-cells-via-tags-fails-due-to-wrong-type) SO answers:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
# Instead of setting the cell to Markdown, create Markdown from withnin a code cell!
# We can just use python variable replacement syntax to make the text dynamic
n = 10
md("The data consists of {} observations. Bla, Bla, ....".format(n))
```

Alternatively, the last line can be simplified as suggested by [@Igor Fobia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812231/print-variable-in-jupyter-notebook-markdown-cell-python#comment101048628_57023238) for Python >3.6:

```
md(f"The data consists of {n} observations. Bla, Bla, ....")
```

This leads to the desired output. However, it has the huge disadvantage that the code cell will still be visible when exporting the NB. This can be solved though:

1. Add a tag to the code cell, i.e. name it "hide"
2. Configure `nbconvert` to ignore the tagged cells, e.g. by adding this `c.TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags = {"hide"}` to your `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` config file

I have written a detailed [blog-post](https://data-dive.com/jupyterlab-markdown-cells-include-variables) about how I implemented this solution for publishing Notebooks on my blog. If you use JupyterLab `< 2.0`, you could install the `jupyterlab-celltags` plugin for JupyterLab to simplify the cell tagging.

Comment: f-string notation works as well: `md(f"The data consists of {n} observations. Bla, Bla, ....")`

Comment: This is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm trying to run this inside a function call, anybody know if that's possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can overwrite `%%markdown` IPython magic to substitute variables from the global environment:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic


@register_cell_magic
def markdown(line, cell):
    return Markdown(cell.format(**globals()))
```

This has the advantage of allowing for Markdown linting when used with JupyterLab-LSP.

If developing a documentation with nbsphinx you can hide the input (source of the cell) by setting `{"hide_input": true}` in cell metadata:

[image]
(note the `Jupyter[Lab]` and `LSP` underlined as those are not in the English dictionary - linting works!)

which results in smooth docs like this:

[image]

For a better experience when in JupyterLab you can always collapse the input cell by clicking on the blue bar to the left of it (visible when you hover over the cell).