# removing certain cells via tags fails due to wrong type

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to hide certain parts of a jupyter notebook and came across tags which can achieve this. I've tagged the cells with `remove_cell` in my notebook an tried to run

```
$ jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags="{'remove_cell'}"
```

however I always get the following error:

```
traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'remove_input_tags' trait of a TagRemovePreprocessor instance must be a set, but a value of type 'unicode' (i.e. u'{remove_cell}') was specified.
```

I've tried to change the `"{'remove_cell'}"` to various format, e.g. `{'remove_cell'}` etc with the same result. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to nbconvert documentation it must be done as you have specified. But there seems to be some bug in command line parsing `traitlets` API, used internally by jupyter nbconvert. So i tried a slightly different approach of specifying Configuration in `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` file.

Steps:

1. `jupyter nbconvert --generate-config`
   This will generate default ~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py.
2. Edit the configuration file and specify your configuration, in this case
   `c.TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags = set(['remove_cell'])`
3. Run `jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb` This will remove the tagged cells and convert it to default HTML page.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Everything goes through now but I still get the input cells. the file looks ok, as there is a tag: `{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 77,
   "metadata": {
    "tags": [
     "remove_cell"
    ]
   },`

Comment: Can you share the test.ipynb file. So that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @math Remember you will still view input cells in notebook (test.ipynb), Only after converting to HTML/other formats the tagged cells will be removed. Hence I suggest you also share `test.html` file.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work without editing the config file by using square brackets, which match the format of the tag in the cell metadata, instead of curly braces.

So, in my cell metadata I have this:

```py
{
    "tags": ["remove_cell"]
}
```

and on the command line I used:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags="['remove_cell']"
```

which successfully removed any cells with this tag from the HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

nbconvert did not hide the cells with tags while also executing the notebook, and this is the most useful example I found here https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1300:
So the underlying issue is that the preprocessors being added on your behalf are un-ordered, so by unlikely chance the --execute turning on the ExecutePreprocessor is getting applied after the TagRemovePreprocessor. To fix this you can set the preprocessors to use in an explicit order by doing:

```
jupyter nbconvert notebooks/demo_notebook.ipynb \
--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags='{"remove-input"}' \
--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_all_outputs_tags='{"remove-output"}' \
--Exporter.preprocessors='["nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor","nbconvert.preprocessors.TagRemovePreprocessor"]' \
--to notebook
```