# How can I write a Python string variable in a Markdown heading?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm working on Jupyter Notebooks and I'd like to write the value of a Python string variable into a Markdown heading. I'm well aware that [one can write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812231/print-variable-in-jupyter-notebook-markdown-cell-python), in a Markdown cell,

```py
# Python
a = 'hello'
```

```html
In a markdown cell, a is {{a}}
```

and this works for me, but I'm trying to do something like

```html
# This is a heading with {{a}} in it
```

But the last attempt didn't work. I googled a little bit, but I couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me, but it is just a code cell; so it might not be the exact functionality you want...

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
a = 'hello'
md("# The data consists of {} observations. Bla, Bla, ....".format(a))
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me, after reading Gerard Rozsavolgyi's post.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do:

```
"This is a string with {{" + a + "}} in it"
```

I guess you're running into issues because '{}' is a reserved 'word' in python strings, and you can solve this issue by splitting the opening and closing brackets.