# Substituting variable in latex output in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, latex, markdown, jupyter

In R markdown, I can easily calculate the values of a equation and output by inserting it in latex to be able to show the equation with the symbol, the substituted values and the final calculated answer.

```
We are given
sample mean = $\mu$= `r sample_mean`
sample standard deviation = $\sigma$ = `r pop_sd`
n = `r n`
Confidence interval = `r CI`
$\alpha/2$ = (1-`r CI`)/2= `r alpha_2`
Using the Normal distribution table, we find the zstat for $\alpha/2$ = `r alpha_2` 
zstat = `r zstat`
SE = $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{`r pop_sd`}{\sqrt{`r n`}}=`r se`$
Margin of error (ME) = $zstat \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=  `r zstat`  \times \frac{`r pop_sd`}{\sqrt{`r n`}}=`r me`$
Confidence Interval = $\mu \pm ME$= ` `r sample_mean`$\pm$ `r me`
Therefore the `r CI*100`% confidence interval for the mean is (`r lower_limit`, `r upper_limit`)
```

The output of the above code in Rmarkdown is as follow.

[image]

I have been trying to get a similar output in Jupyter notebook, but the substituting of python variable is giving me an error incase of \frac{}{}.

Note : I do understand from some other question on stakoverflow we need to use {{}} but this not really working in every case.

Can some one guide me as to how I can substitute and get well format output in jupyter. I need to repelicate it this in jupter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing nbextensions per nilansh bansal's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874352/8303875)?

Comment: Yes tried it but it not fulfilling my requirement. The example given  by Nilansh does not seem to be working for \frac{}{} or more complicated equation.