Jupyter notebook open relative link to an html page outside the notebook
I am using jupyter notebook and I want to make a link to a local HTML page.
The standard solution of course seem to work :
<a href="../doc/code/doxygen/class_object.html" target="_blank">link</a>  
[Object](../doc/code/doxygen/class_object.html)

But actually it opens the html without the css. It looks like the html page is actually opened by jupyter and not directly by the browser : the adress is :
http://localhost:XXXX/files/doc/code/doxygen/class_object.html

Instead of just :
file:///XXXXXXXXXXX/doc/code/doxygen/class_object.html

I would really like Jupyter to open the link like it does for an external link ; for example the following opens the page directly in the browser :
<a href="https://rebellion.global" target="_blank">link</a>

Any tips ?

This won't be possible; file: urls must be absolute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files

I see, but is there a way to go through without using file: ?
Or maybe a way to script this, something like : file:///{os.getcwd}/bla.html ?

It seems a way would be to use indeed the path store in a python varible :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878083/can-i-use-variables-on-an-ipython-notebook-markup-cell
seems hacky thuw, and users would have to re-run markdown cells. or would they ?

Linking to local files in the first place is a hacky solution (your users will need to have the exact files stored on their devices located in the exact right place, which you'll have no way to control) -- I'd strongly recommend you host these files at actual URLs.
